# Android Studio How can I create edittext with number of string characters?

Tags: java, android

I want to create such a view with edittext.I have to create edittext as much as the char in the incoming string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dygKJ.png)

I previously defined a linerLayout in my activity_main.xml file. Then I created edittext into it. my last view is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic6Q0.png)

my code is as follows

```
public void init() {

    question = new ArrayList<>();
    question.add("hello");
    question.add("heyo");
    question.add("Everyone");

    final ArrayList<EditText>[] array_edit_text = new ArrayList[question.size()];

    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.game_questions_relative_layout);


    for (int j = 0; j < question.size(); j++) {

        array_edit_text[j] = new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams2.setMargins(10, 20, 10, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < question.get(j).length(); i++) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout3 = new LinearLayout(this);

            linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearLayout3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setText("    ");
            editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            array_edit_text[j].add(editText);
            linearLayout3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background_5dp);
            linearLayout3.addView(editText, layoutParams3);

            linearLayout2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            linearLayout2.addView(linearLayout3, layoutParams2);
        }
        linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2);
    }
}
```

but my problem is I can't switch between these edittexts. when the character is entered I have to switch to another. or clicking the delete button should switch to the previous one

Please can you help me? I cannot progress the program. Thank you from now...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the Text Watcher class and then set the focus on the next EditText in the OnTextChanged() method of the TextWatcher.

In your case, You can try out the following code:-

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
    {
        if(//some condition) //if some condition focus the next edit text
        {
            array_edit_text[j+1].requestFocus();
        }


         if(//some condition) //if some other condition focus the previousedit text
        {
            array_edit_text[j-1].requestFocus();
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});
```

Comment: sorry, unfortunately, I have to define "i" and "j" variables as "final" and unfortunately, I cannot reach the next edittex when I do.

Comment: you can copy i and j into final variables inside the loop. and i did not understand the second part of your comment. either way, maybe you'll need to refactor your code in some way to make it work, but my answer simply shows you how you can change focus between edittexts, whenever text changes in one of them. how exactly you implement it and the logic you use for it is up to you

Comment: Also, if doing this inside the for you're creating your edit texts in, consider simply doing this after your first for, when all your edit texts are already created in the ArrayList

Comment: --  file:///tmp/Spectacle.YRvPtK/Screenshot_20200831_220300.png  --


This is what I want to tell. I have to define it as "final" to use the values. but I can't change the "final" variable so I can't access the next editText

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) ? You can use the following code.

```
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // setFocus to the next Edittext
        nextEditText.requestFocus();
    }
};
```

Then you can associate the TextWatcher to your editText.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
```

Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Comment: I tried this use, but when I return all edittexts with for, when I create this method for each edittext, I cannot reach the next edittex. I have to define the loop values ​​as "final".